# Rewriting SQL query to display rows where match=1 isn't found

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find rows in which ts_request.day_id and ts_request.period_id do not equal 1 and do not exist.

How can I go about doing this?

My current SQL query looks like it is searching for rows where a match is found - I'm looking for rows where a match isn't round (because the row doesn't exist).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) totalCount FROM ts_room 
JOIN ts_roompref
ON ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id 
JOIN ts_request 
ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
WHERE ts_request.day_id = 1 
AND ts_request.period_id = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the row doesn't exist you need to change your INNER JOIN to a LEFT OUTER JOIN. Because the definition of an INNER JOIN is that it brings back only those records for which the join-condition evaluates to true.

Then to get just the records with no matching rows, add one or more conditions to your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 

  JOIN ts_roompref
  ON ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id 

  LEFT JOIN ts_request 
  ON ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id
WHERE 
  ts_request.day_id IS NULL;
```

---

Another way to write the above query is:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) totalCount 
FROM 
  ts_room 

  JOIN ts_roompref
  ON ts_room.id = ts_roompref.room_id 

WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM ts_request 
    WHERE ts_roompref.request_id = ts_request.roompref_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Bernie, I've edited my SQL query slightly because it kept returning 0 records. I've uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/M9PwDgkd. Not sure why it isn't working. Here is my table structure: http://i.imgur.com/Pr9qumb.png - ts_request, http://i.imgur.com/pQMuBL3.png - ts_room, http://i.imgur.com/NLNO0wt.png - ts_roompref

Comment: I realise that there is roompref_id in ts_request so this must be why I keep getting 0 records :-( - my bad!!! How would I go about rewording the SQL query now?

Comment: Do you mean to say that there are no rows with NULL `roompref_id` in the `ts_request` table?

Comment: Yes there are no rows in the ts_request table at the moment so the query should return all the rooms as being available

Comment: How many rows are in the other two tables? Would you be able to put some sample data for testing here?: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: The whole idea is that there will be 93 records returned because no requests have been made for any of the rooms

Comment: This query returns a count of 16 -- a count of all the sample records since none has any requests: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30297/5

Comment: Sorry! Yeah that's right. So if I add the correlating room request with day_id=1 and period_id=1 it will go down to 15?

Comment: Well since the test data aren't as complete as your actual data it doesn't reflect here, but the query would be like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30297/7

Answer (score 0):

Hi use <> is the same as not equal...  where <> 1
Understand or youvneed an example